# Running a privileged docker container in Openshift

Tags: docker, openshift, privileges, sysctl

I am currently trying to modify some kernel parameters inside my docker image with `sysctl -p` and the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`.

Before trying to do it inside Openshift, i just executed `docker run --privileged ...` and it worked, but now i need to deploy and run the container in Openshift Origin 3.6.0. The problem is I don't have access to the SCCs in Openshift, as I'm not an administrator in my Openshift server, so I'm wondering if is there any way to do it without modifying the SCCs.

Is there any way to specify in `oc new-app ...` the parameters I need to run in the `docker run ...`?

In case not, the only way to do it is including my project inside the privileged SCC in the Openshift Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not an administrator, and can't get an administrator to create you a service account in your project which gives you the required rights, no you will not be able to do it.

What sort of application are you trying to run which needs such elevated privileges?

Comment: I would like to do this in order to run dind (Docker in Docker) for a build/test container